# Android xml or create dynamically?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am wondering what option is better, create xml file with his layouts, images, buttons or should I create those from java code dynamically. What's your advice? I am trying create application more faster and efficient.

Comment: My advice is use XML layouts only. Its very easy and fast if you understand it only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

simple, if your application is *flexible*(for multi screen) then go for Java programming else you can do by creating specific xml layouts

Comment: no, as you cant set the control(textview, imageview etc..) height width in percentage term as per screen size availibility

Comment: One can build flexible layouts with XML which works in low density,medium density,high density and small,medium and large screen sizes.  Building UI dynamically with java, layout inflator,etc is also a good option and   some situations it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages it's faster to declare things statically, since these parts can be optimized by the compiler.

You should only do the layout stuff in java code if you have an app which needs dynamic layout (Such as a custom list with a dynamic number of entries).

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for XML layouts by default and only choose Java code if you have a specific reason.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally advisable to go with xml. That's mainly because it apparently parses faster. I prefer xml layouts.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is using XML as much as I can (basically if you use static views). When the views have some dynamical content you'd better go for Java programming.